# How to effectively embed Python code into Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Guys how to embed efficiently python code into Django.

I have a Django template where it takes value from user, then the request goes to DB and look for the value.

Also I have my python code with formulas with values that are based on number retrieved from the DB.

```
view.py


def home(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
              form=PersonForm(request.POST)
              if form.is_valid():
                  form1=form.save(commit=True)
                  name=form1.name

                obj=School.objects.get(student=name)

                context={  'object':obj }
                return render(request, 'book/analysis.html', context)

         else:
             form = PersonForm()
            return render(request, 'book/search.html', {'object':obj})
```

In the past I used to insert python code inside this home(request) function, however my code is bit lengthy and I would like to create separate file and insert there. What worries me is in my python code I define values such as

```
formula.py


math_score_final=object.math
math_score_final=object.biology

final=(math_score_final+math_score_final)/2
```

Is this a correct way to do it?

How would you advice to reorganise my code to make the web function smoothly?

Would appreciate your insight on this matter.

Comment: Your "Django" code **is python** so you can define any function in another python file and import it and use it anywhere including in a Django view (which is just a python function).

Comment: so in formula.py file i can define values that are taken from DB without any need to import from view.py?

Comment: no it's the other way round. In your view you import some function from formula.py and call it. e.g. `def calculate_score(object): .... return final`

Comment: but first view.py takes values from a user and based on it goes to DB takes values based on a student name and based on it I can define math_score_final. So you say I can define math_score_final=object.math in formula.py and it would not generate error?

Comment: not if you define a **function** in formula.py and **call it** passing `object` (btw never call any variable `object` since that is a **reserved** keyword in python).

Comment: so what I wrote is correct way : math_score_final=object.math? no need to import in the file anything?

Comment: can you please share some code it would be clear for me is I see. would appreciate your help.

Comment: Well the code you show here won't work obviously (`object` is the base python class so `object.math` is going to throw an error). Please write the function you want to use in formula.py and then import it in views.py. Then if you still get an error, show us your code in a new question.